# Using さ as an interjection

Tags: interjections

I sometimes see a single さ at the end of a sentence, not being appended to an adjective of either type, so I determined that this さ must be an interjection or a 語尾｛ごび｝ of some type. Thus, what meaning does さ used as an interjection/語尾 convey, or is it more of a matter of personal preferences?

Comment: 例文はないですか？「わかっている**さ** 。」「君はまだシンデレラ**さ** 。」「そう**さ** 。」などとは異なる、文末の「さ」ですか？

Comment: (cont.) もし上のコメントに挙げた例文のような文末の「さ」であれば、duplicate とされた質問の「さ」とは違いますね。「 **さ**あ、行きましょう」の「さ」は "now" "come on" などの意、「でも**さ**あ」「あの**さ**あ」「それで**さ**あ」の「さ」は filler, でも、「わかっている**さ** 。」（≂わかっているよ。）「君はシンデレラ**さ** 。」（≂君はシンデレラだ。/だよ。）「そう**さ** 。」（≂そうだ。/だよ。）の「さ」は終助詞ですので。